# My PHP Contact Form Won't Send

Tags: php, javascript, html, forms, contacts

This certainly does seem to be a popular question! Firstly, I sincerely apologise for repeating the question. I have tried several fixes used in different questions and haven't found anything which can fix my problem yet.

I have created a website that essentially wants to send a query from the contact form to me. i will try to define my problems: 
1. I am expecting an error message to come up which says 'Name is a required field', or similar, however this doesn't. 
2. When pressing submit the page takes me to a blank page that directs me to my mail_form.php on my server.

Of note, my servers is 123-reg who say that they do allow user scripts but also provide their own example of one to use - I have tried this to no avail.

I'm not 100% sure what you'll ask to see so I'll provide my jsfiddle and the relevant bits:

My jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/c9Sug/

My PHP:

```
<?php


    $yourEmail = "SARVAN14@HOTMAIL.COM"; // the email address you wish to receive these mails through
    $yourWebsite = "HTTP://WWW.SSWEBTEST.CO.UK"; // the name of your website
    $thanksPage = 'thankyou.html'; // URL to 'thanks for sending mail' page; leave empty to keep message on the same page 
    $maxPoints = 4; // max points a person can hit before it refuses to submit - recommend 4




$error_msg = null;
$result = null;

function isBot() {
    $bots = array("Indy", "Blaiz", "Java", "libwww-perl", "Python", "OutfoxBot", "User-Agent", "PycURL", "AlphaServer", "T8Abot", "Syntryx", "WinHttp", "WebBandit", "nicebot");

    $isBot = false;
    foreach ($bots as $bot)
    if (strpos($_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'], $bot) !== false)
        $isBot = true;

    if (empty($_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT']) || $_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'] == " ")
        $isBot = true;

    exit("Bots not allowed.</p>");
}

if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == "POST") {
    function clean($data) {
        $data = trim(stripslashes(strip_tags($data)));
        return $data;
    }

    $points = (int)0;

    $badwords = array("adult", "beastial", "bestial", "blowjob", "clit", "cum", "cunilingus", "cunillingus", "cunnilingus", "cunt", "ejaculate", "fag", "felatio", "fellatio", "fuck", "fuk", "fuks", "gangbang", "gangbanged", "gangbangs", "hotsex", "hardcode", "jism", "jiz", "orgasim", "orgasims", "orgasm", "orgasms", "phonesex", "phuk", "phuq", "porn", "pussies", "pussy", "spunk", "xxx", "viagra", "phentermine", "tramadol", "adipex", "advai", "alprazolam", "ambien", "ambian", "amoxicillin", "antivert", "blackjack", "backgammon", "texas", "holdem", "poker", "carisoprodol", "ciara", "ciprofloxacin", "debt", "dating", "porn", "link=", "voyeur");
    $exploits = array("content-type", "bcc:", "cc:", "document.cookie", "onclick", "onload", "javascript");

    foreach ($badwords as $word)
        if (strpos($_POST['comments'], $word) !== false)
            $points += 2;

    foreach ($exploits as $exploit)
        if (strpos($_POST['comments'], $exploit) !== false)
            $points += 2;

    if (strpos($_POST['comments'], "http://") !== false || strpos($_POST['comments'], "www.") !== false)
        $points += 2;
    if (isset($_POST['nojs']))
        $points += 1;
    if (preg_match("/(<.*>)/i", $_POST['comments']))
        $points += 2;
    if (strlen($_POST['name']) < 3)
        $points += 1;
    if (strlen($_POST['comments']) < 15 || strlen($_POST['comments'] > 1500))
        $points += 2;

    foreach ($_POST as $key => $value)
        $_POST[$key] = trim($value);

    if (empty($_POST['name']) || empty($_POST['email']) || empty($_POST['comments'])) {
        $error_msg .= "Name, e-mail and comments are required fields. \n";
    } elseif (strlen($_POST['name']) > 15) {
        $error_msg .= "The name field is limited at 15 characters. Your first name or nickname will do! \n";
    } elseif (!preg_match("/^[a-zA-Z-'\s]*$/", stripslashes($_POST['name']))) {
        $error_msg .= "The name field must not contain special characters. \n";
    } elseif (!preg_match('/^([a-z0-9])(([-a-z0-9._])*([a-z0-9]))*\@([a-z0-9])(([a-z0-9-])*([a-z0-9]))+' . '(\.([a-z0-9])([-a-z0-9_-])?([a-z0-9])+)+$/i', strtolower($_POST['email']))) {
        $error_msg .= "That is not a valid e-mail address. \n";
    } elseif (!empty($_POST['url']) && !preg_match('/^(http|https):\/\/(([A-Z0-9][A-Z0-9_-]*)(\.[A-Z0-9][A-Z0-9_-]*)+)(:(\d+))?\/?/i', $_POST['url']))
        $error_msg .= "Invalid website url.";

    if ($error_msg == NULL && $points <= $maxPoints) {
        $subject = "Automatic Form Email";

        $message = "You received this e-mail message through your website: \n\n";
        foreach ($_POST as $key => $val) {
            $message .= ucwords($key) . ": " . clean($val) . "\r\n";
        }
        $message .= 'IP: '.$_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']."\r\n";
        $message .= 'Browser: '.$_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT']."\r\n";
        $message .= 'Points: '.$points;

        if (strstr($_SERVER['SERVER_SOFTWARE'], "Win")) {
            $headers   = "From: $yourEmail \r\n";
            $headers  .= "Reply-To: {$_POST['email']}";
        } else {
            $headers   = "From: $yourWebsite <$yourEmail> \r\n";
            $headers  .= "Reply-To: {$_POST['email']}";
        }

        if (mail($yourEmail,$subject,$message,$headers)) {
            if (!empty($thanksPage)) {
                header("Location: $thanksPage");
                exit;
            } else {
                $result = 'Your mail was successfully sent.';
            }
        } else {
            $error_msg = 'Your mail could not be sent this time.';
        }
    } else {
        if (empty($error_msg))
            $error_msg = 'Your mail looks too much like spam, and could not be sent this time. ['.$points.']';
    }
}
function get_data($var) {
    if (isset($_POST[$var]))
        echo htmlspecialchars($_POST[$var]);
}
?>
```

My validation.css:

```
.forms li {
  overflow: hidden;
  list-style-type:none;
}


em.error {
  clear: both; display: block;
  font-size: 12px; font-style:italic; color: #f00;
  margin: -10px 0 10px 175px; width:200px;
}

input, textarea { padding:5px; }
```

My validation.js:

```
/*
 * Simple jQuery Form Validation Plugin
 * http://github.com/davist11/jQuery-Simple-Validate
 *
 * Copyright (c) 2010 Trevor Davis (http://trevordavis.net)
 * Dual licensed under the MIT and GPL licenses.
 * Uses the same license as jQuery, see:
 * http://jquery.org/license
 *
 * @version 0.1
 */
;(function(b){b.fn.simpleValidate=function(l){var g=b.extend({},b.fn.simpleValidate.defaults,l);return this.each(function(){var d=b(this),a=b.meta?b.extend({},g,d.data()):g,h=a.errorText.search(/{label}/);d.bind("submit",function(i){var f=false;d.find(a.errorElement+"."+a.errorClass).remove();d.find(":input."+a.inputErrorClass).removeClass(a.inputErrorClass);d.find(":input.required").each(function(){var e=b(this),j=b.trim(e.val()),k=e.siblings("label").text().replace(a.removeLabelChar,""),c="";if(j===
""){c=h>-1?(c=a.errorText.replace("{label}",k)):(c=a.errorText);f=true}else if(e.hasClass("email"))if(!/^([_a-z0-9-]+)(\.[_a-z0-9-]+)*@([a-z0-9-]+)(\.[a-z0-9-]+)*(\.[a-z]{2,4})$/.test(j)){c=h>-1?(c=a.emailErrorText.replace("{label}",k)):(c=a.emailErrorText);f=true}c!==""&&e.addClass(a.inputErrorClass).after("<"+a.errorElement+' class="'+a.errorClass+'">'+c+"</"+a.errorElement+">")});if(f)i.preventDefault();else if(a.completeCallback!==""){a.completeCallback(d);a.ajaxRequest&&i.preventDefault()}})})};
b.fn.simpleValidate.defaults={errorClass:"error",errorText:"{label} is a required field.",emailErrorText:"Please enter a valid {label}",errorElement:"strong",removeLabelChar:"*",inputErrorClass:"",completeCallback:"",ajaxRequest:false}})(jQuery);
```

Thank you so much in advance!

Comment: Hmmm. As for me - all is correct (on js/html side), I haven't used this plugin, but I used [this one](http://bassistance.de/jquery-plugins/jquery-plugin-validation/) several times in different projects and all worked well. Here I see that form is submitted immediately, without highlighting wrongly filled field.

Comment: I couldn't figure out why that one wouldn't work so I've rehashed it and made a new contact form using the example given by dreamweavertutorial.co.uk. Thank for everyone's keen looking at my script!

Comment: You seem to be rejecting the word "hardcode", which I don't think is anybody's definition of a swear.

Answer (score 0):

I did something very similar not too long ago and got very frustrated with the same problem. Turns out emails were getting sent to my spam folder. You should check there to see if you indeed are recieving the emails or not. Even though all the same headers were filled, they still end up there.